# How to print the decimal value of a `std::bitset` bigger than a `unsigned long long`?

Tags: c++, converters

I'm programming a class to handle integers with a bitset with more bits of a `unsigned long long`.

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

#define MAX_BITS 32000

class RossInt {
    std::bitset<MAX_BITS> bits;

public:
    RossInt(unsigned long long num); /* Copies the bits of num into the bitset */
    RossInt operator+ (const RossInt& op) const;

    std::string to_string() const; /* Returns the number in decimal in a string */
};
```

Since the number is bigger than a `unsigned long long` I'll put it in a string, but the issue is that I can't use the way I would normally use with the `decimal_n += pow(2, bit_index)` cause I can't store the result into a variable and I want to use as less external library as possible.
Is there a way for converting it using bitwise operators or any other way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: We  can only consult the crystal-ball for what your *"new int type that is bigger than a long long int."* is -- and right now it isn't working very well. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you looked at any of the large integer implementations (e.g., [Boost's Integer Types](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints.html))?

Comment: No, I want to create my own integer. It's more like an excerise than something I really need for work or so

Comment: I believe your question could use a better title and better introduction (getting rid of introducing your big integer implementation). Something among the lines of: "*How to print the decimal value represented by `std::bitset` that is too big to fit in `unsigned long long`?*". I think it's a great question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loosing two nights on it, I've finally found a way of printing it. It's not the most efficient way and I'm gonna rewrite it until I'm satisfied with the speed.

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const RossInt& value) {
    RossInt op = value;
    RossInt i = 1;
    while (op / i > 0) i = i * 10;

    do {
        i = i / 10;
        os << (op / i).to_ullong();
        op = op % i;
    } while (i > 1);

    return os;
}
```

The logic used in this code is pretty simple: if x = y and I divide both of them by 10^x, x is still equal to y. Using this property I wrote a code that prints the number digit by digit.
The first line copies the number to avoid changes in the value.

```cpp
    RossInt i = 1;
    while (op / i > 0) i = i * 10;
```

The initial value of `i` is `1`, the neutral number for multiplications. In the `while` it keeps increasing `i` until it gets bigger than the value of the number making possible to know the number of digit of the number without converting it in decimal.

```cpp
    do {
        i = i / 10;
        os << (op / i).to_ullong();
        op = op % i;
    } while (i > 1);
```

This cycle is used to do the real print of the number. 
With every iteration the `i` loose a 0. Dividing `op` by `i` removes as many digits from the bottom of `op` as many `0`s `i` has. Ex.: `12345 / 100 = 123`.
The operation right after that does the exact opposite: it keeps as many digits as the `0`s instead of removing them.
This cycle then print a digit and remove it right after, passing and printing them all.

Comment: "*The first line copies the number to avoid changes in the value.*" - in that case it's better to pass by value, i.e., `RossInt value` instead of `const RossInt& value` and avoid copying it inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a Binary->[BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) (Binary Coded Decimal) solution. Once you have a BCD, printing it is easy.
Given BCD math is heavily used I tried looking for a standard solution, but could not find one.

This example class should help. It's not traditional BCD representation, but it's easier to follow.

```
class BCD
{
public:
    // function to make the "root" value.
    static BCD One()     { BCD retval; retval.digits = {1}; return retval; }
    // we will generate all powers of two from doubling from one
    void Double()
    {
        for(auto& d : digits) d *= 2;
        Normalise();
    }
    // We can generate all other numbers by combining powers of two.
    void operator+=(const BCD& other)
    {
        if (other.digits.size()>digits.size())
            digits.resize(other.digits.size(), 0);
        std::transform(digits.begin(), digits.end(), other.digits.begin(), digits.begin(), std::plus<char>{});    
        Normalise();
    }
    friend inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const BCD&);
private:
        // "normal form" is all digits 0-9, if required carry the one 
        void Normalise()
        {
            int carry = 0;
            for(auto& d : digits) {
                d+=carry;
                carry = d/10;
                d = d%10;
            }
            if (carry) digits.push_back(carry);
        }
        std::vector<char> digits;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BCD& bcd)
{
    for_each(bcd.digits.rbegin(), bcd.digits.rend(), [&os](char d){ os << (char)(d+'0'); });
}
```

Using this class it should be simple to build a BCD from a bitset. For example

```
int main()
{
    BCD power_of_two = BCD::One();
    BCD total;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        total += power_of_two;
        std::cout << power_of_two <<  " total = " << total << "\n";
        power_of_two.Double();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
1 total = 1
2 total = 3
4 total = 7
8 total = 15
16 total = 31
32 total = 63
64 total = 127
128 total = 255
256 total = 511
512 total = 1023
```

all you have to do is make the "+=" conditional on the bit in the set. I'm not claiming this is the best way to do it, but it should be good enough to test your results.
Hope it helps

-----------------Update after comments----------

It has been pointed out that my solution is not a complete solution.
In the spirit of being helpful I will provide how you can use the BCD class above to build a "to_string" function.
If you don't understand this you have to read up on [number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number). You have to do it this way because 10=5*2. 5 is odd, and therefore there is no 10^x = 2^y, where x and y are integers. In practice, this means that the first digit in the decimal representation depends on every digit in the binary representation. You must determine it by adding all the powers of two. You may as well generate the whole number using the same logic.
Please be advised though that stack overflow exists to help programmers who have got stuck, not to do other peoples work for them. Please do not expect to have other people post working programs for you.

```
std::string to_string() const
{
    BCD power_of_two = BCD::One();
    BCD total;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < bits.size(); ++idx) {
        if (bits.test(idx))
            total += power_of_two;
        power_of_two.Double();
    }
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << total;
    return os.str();
}
```

Comment: I've looked up about BCD and how they work and I thank you. I didn't know of this way of writing decimal numbers, but I still want to find a way to convert the bitset

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Storing big integers as a vectors of digits makes outputting trivial. What's not trivial (begin the topic of this question) is how to convert an arbitraly big binary representation to its decimal counterpart.